Zabbix certain Graphs in Dashboard don't work anymore
The "new" Graphes worked a while back, but now they are just blank and dont display anything anymore. Now only a handfull work.
The "classic" Graphs work fine, even with the values that aren't working for the new ones.
Anybody got any idea ?
Empty Graphs
Some Work some don't
